# How to make pandas.DataFrame.rank to start from 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rank

How to make

```
pandas.DataFrame.rank(pct=True)
```

to start from 0?

For example, if I have 11 numbers in a column, `rank` will yield `0.0909, 0.1818, ..., 1.0000`. I want it to yield `0.0000, 0.1000, ..., 1.0000`.

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: You mean this , `pd.DataFrame.rank(ascending=False, pct=true)`

Comment: can you  share your dataframe or code you tested?

Comment: `pct=True` gives you rank in percentages. If you want your ranks to be just whole numbers like `1.0, 2.0, 3.0`, you can simply remove the pct condition. If you want your rank in fractions, then I guess you need to apply some math on your rank logic as suggested in the answer by @helcode.

Answer (score 3):

You can subtract `1/n` then normalize by `(n-1)/n` (where `n` is the number of items in the column).

Code for your case,

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
count = df.count()[0]
(df.rank(pct=True) - 1/count) * count/(count-1)
```

Above code yields,

```
    col1
0    0.0
1    0.1
2    0.2
3    0.3
4    0.4
5    0.5
6    0.6
7    0.7
8    0.8
9    0.9
10   1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas method [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html?highlight=rank#pandas.DataFrame.rank) and then subtract 1

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['col1'].rank(method='first')-1
```

return

```
0      0.0
1      1.0
2      2.0
3      3.0
4      4.0
5      5.0
6      6.0
7      7.0
8      8.0
9      9.0
10    10.0
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```